# "Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed" on nested ssh

Tags: debian, login, openssh

I have a gateway to ssh into from the bad world wide web. No problem, I get:

```
remote ~$ ssh -X ingo@gateway
Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
0:ingo@gateway ~$
```

Now I manage my other hosts, for example the fileserver:

```
0:ingo@gateway ~$ ssh -X ingo@fileserver
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
0:ingo@fileserver~$
```

I get that Warning.

But if I ssh from my management host on the local network direct into the fileserver, it works without the Warning. I have verified this with other logins. I only get the Warning when ssh from a ssh.

Why do I get
**Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated**
only on nested ssh logins?

How can I avoid this warning and can successful use the more secure untrusted X11 forwarding?

And no, I do not want to use the less secure `-Y` option on ssh for trusted X11 forwarding instead of the used `-X` option.

Comment: You should either use trusted X11 forwarding for the 1st forwarding, or use the intermediate host(s) as jump host(s) via the `-J` option. Otherwise it will not work. I'm sorry if you don't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your only connection to an X11 server is *untrusted*, you cannot forward it further.

The untrusted X11 forwarding works by the ssh client connecting to the local display, and using the `xauth generate $DISPLAY . untrusted` command to generate an *untrusted* key / cookie.

But for that, the `xauth` command needs the `SECURITY` extension to be present on the display, which, like most extensions is hidden and/or disabled when a client like `xauth` was authenticated with an untrusted cookie.

You can easily check that with:

```
$ touch /tmp/junk1 /tmp/junk2
$ chmod 600 /tmp/junk*
$ xauth -f /tmp/junk1 generate :0 . untrusted
$ XAUTHORITY=/tmp/junk1 oclock
   # get a square oclock because the Shape extension is disabled
$ XAUTHORITY=/tmp/junk1 xdpyinfo | grep -A2 extensions
number of extensions:    2
    BIG-REQUESTS
    XC-MISC
   # vs 28 or so on a trusted display
$ XAUTHORITY=/tmp/junk1 xauth -f /tmp/junk2 generate :0 . untrusted
xauth: (argv):1:  couldn't query Security extension on display ":0"
```

The latter step will cause the warning you get in ssh.

So at least the first X11 forwarding should be trusted, otherwise it would not work.

---

Alternatively, you should "jump" through the intermediate host, which will do a single X11 forwarding:

```
ssh -X -o ForwardX11Trusted=no -J ingo@gateway ingo@fileserver
```

Notice that explicit `ForwardX11Trusted=no`, because on Debian, the `-X` and `-Y` options are equivalent, and you'll get a *trusted* X11 forwarding by default no matter which one you're using.